# how to test android in-app billing RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS without purchasing item

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I am using Android Billing library for selling Managed products. But I want to test RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS without purchasing any Managed product to see how it works.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your best bet for info I would guess :)

http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_testing.html

Comment: but there is nothing about testing RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS

Comment: :( I did say guess, I found another question on stackoverflow though now that said the only way to test was with real transactions